# All Queries in a given transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am currently trying to debug "idle in transaction" scenarios in my application.I can find out the process id and transaction start time for a query with state 'idle in transaction' by looking at pg_state_activity.

```
select pid,query from pg_stat_activity where state='idle in transaction' OR state='idle'
```

Is there any way to identify list of all queries executed within a transaction corresponding to the query with 'idle in transaction'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you attempting to get a list of *all previous statements run by the transaction that is now showing up as idle in transaction*?

If so, there is no easy and safe way to do so at the SQL level. You should use CSV logging mode to analyze your query history and group queries up into transactions. Handily, you can do this with SQL, by `COPY`ing the CSV into a PostgreSQL table for easier analysis.

Alternately, use ordinary text logs, and set a `log_line_prefix` that includes the transaction ID and process ID.

(I could've sworn I saw an extension for debugging that collected a query trace, but cannot find it now, and I'm not sure it's that useful as you must run a command *on the problem connection* to extract the data it's collected).